# How to duplicate a .xib file?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xib

I see there's no "duplicate" when I right click on a .xib. So is the way to do it: just to go to finder, copy the file to another name, and then drag it to my resources? Would that be all I'd need to do?

[Note: just wondering if there's other files or settings I need to bother with.]

Comment: this is what I've had to do in the past.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, that's most of what's needed. Make sure to open the nib file and verify that the connections are as you want them to be. It will act like any file you duplicate. Just give it an original name and make sure it's saved in the correct folder before you import it into the project.

Comment: After copying, my xib was still associated with the original .m file and wouldn't allow connections to the new one. I needed to update the xib's "Custom Class" field under File's Owner. (Xcode 6.1.1)

Answer (score 48):

The best way to do this is use cmd ⌘ ,shift, s on the xib or storyboard. Then save it with a new name or location.

Comment: This is the easiest way to do it, and also the safest, I reckon.

Comment: I think this is the easiest for nw. Thanks

Comment: Note this is the `Duplicate` option under the `File` menu.

Answer (score 1):

yes , you can copy the the contents of the xib file by just (command+c) and paste it into another xib file by using (command +v) but by simply cop and pasting you won't get the references you need to go the properties in xib file there you need to give the class name for which you have created a new xib file and then it will give you the references.